# Override per-directory settings on a file type basis

Tags: directory-local-variables

I'm using `dir-locals-set-class-variables` in my git directories to apply whitespace-mode settings differently, based on the needs of each repo. if my `sf` directory, for all subfolders, I want to use tabs for spacing. But for markdown files inside those directories, I want to continue to use spaces instead of tabs.

Is there a way to apply an even more granular override so that in directories where I'm applying this setting:

```
(dir-locals-set-class-variables 'sf
                                '((nil . ((whitespace-style . (empty
                                                               face
                                                               indentation empty
                                                               lines-tail
                                                               space-after-tab
                                                               space-before-tab
                                                               trailing))
                                          (indent-tabs-mode . t)
                                          (tab-width . 4)
                                          (tab-stop-list . (number-sequence 4 200 4))
                                          ;; (indent-line-function . 'insert-spaces)
                                          (sgml-basic-offset . 4)))))
```

that I could then have markdown files to use spaces versus tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't typically perform overrides to the default (`nil`) case on a per *file type* basis, but on a per *major mode* basis (and in your case the latter is most likely what you want, assuming you have a `markdown-mode` installed to handle markdown files).

```el
(dir-locals-set-class-variables
 'sf
 '((nil . ((whitespace-style . (empty
                                face
                                indentation empty
                                lines-tail
                                space-after-tab
                                space-before-tab
                                trailing))
           (indent-tabs-mode . t)
           (tab-width . 4)
           (tab-stop-list . (number-sequence 4 200 4))
           ;; (indent-line-function . 'insert-spaces)
           (sgml-basic-offset . 4)))
   (markdown-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)))))
```

For more information, refer to:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Directory Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>